# Make array from Requests.get in python

Tags: python, flask

I Do the following :

```
@app.route('/api/test/', methods=['GET'])
def catalogue1():
 cache = []
 r = requests.get("http://192.168.198.140:5000/api/listdir")
 cache = r.content
```

cache = ["vagrant.txt", "Securite_sociale.jpg"] ;

when i try to print cache[0] i get "[" .

How can i transform this result to an array .

Comment: Tangential, but the line `cache = []` is not required

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about Flask but it looks like `r.content` is a string, yet to be de-serialized into a Python list. e.g. rather than

```
cache = ["vagrant.txt", "Securite_sociale.jpg"]
```

you have:

```
cache = '["vagrant.txt", "Securite_sociale.jpg"]'
```

I'm presuming it's JSON, in which case you could fix this with

```
import json
cache = json.loads(r.content)
```

But I'm also presuming there's a built-in way to do this in Flask